# C# - Revit - Length and orientation of a part

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have just developed an algorithm to retrieve all the shares of a Revit project with the original category "Walls".
I would now like to retrieve the length and orientation of each of these walls (which are parts), the Element.Location property returns "null", as if the creation of a part removes the data relating to the geometry of the object.

One solution would be to find the parent of each of my parts by comparing their IFCGuid but it seems rather complicated to get only the length and orientation of my walls.

Do you have another solution to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Hugo

Answer (score 0):

With walls you should have a result with this:

```
Wall wall = yourElement as Wall;
Curve curve = (wall.Location as LocationCurve).Curve;
```

You should then be able to get lenght and orientation from the wall curve.

Good Luck

Fançois